# Compare among duplicated rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to check if a duplicated row's date is between the two dates

[image]

This is a dummy dataset. Here There are duplicated records for customer X. I want to see all records of customer X in which the 'Call' date comes in between the previous record of Customer X's 'Call Date' and 'DateCreated'.

For example, I want the second customer X's record since 'Call' Date is between the previous one's Call and Datecreated.
[image]

But I do not want the third record of X since the Call Date is not between the previous record's Dates.

I am totally stuck. One way I did it was by grouping records based on customer and Call date and then iterating over my whole dataset and checking in the group which one satisfies my condition. But I don't think it's an efficient way. Is there a way in which I can solve this problem?

Comment: Could you please provide some test data (not a picture), this is almost impossible to recreate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'customer':['x','x','y','x','a'],
                   'status':['active','canceled','active','active','canciled'],
                   'call':['2019-01-02','2019-01-01','2019-01-03','2019-01-04','2019-01-05'],
                   'dateCreated':['2018-12-31','2019-01-01','2019-01-03','2019-01-04','2019-01-05']})
df['call'] = pd.to_datetime(df['call'])
df['dateCreated'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dateCreated'])
```

This sets up the data

```
    customer    status      call        dateCreated
0   x           active      2019-01-02  2018-12-31
1   x           canceled    2019-01-01  2019-01-01
2   y           active      2019-01-03  2019-01-03
3   x           active      2019-01-04  2019-01-04
4   a           canciled    2019-01-05  2019-01-05
```

Then this does the work

```
notNeeded = [False] * len(df["customer"])  # create new column
df['notNeeded'] = notNeeded

for i in range(len(df['call'])):
    curr_call = df['call'][i]
    curr_cust = df['customer'][i] 
    for j in range(i,-1,-1): # only look at previous rows
        if df['customer'][j] == curr_cust: # only look at the same customer
            if df['notNeeded'][j] is not True: # check this has not been removed
                if df['dateCreated'][j] < curr_call < df['call'][j]: # check if the day is between
                    df['notNeeded'][i] = True # set the mark to get rid of it
```

Then this yields

```
    customer    status      call        dateCreated notNeeded
0   x           active      2019-01-02  2018-12-31  False
1   x           canceled    2019-01-01  2019-01-01  True
2   y           active      2019-01-03  2019-01-03  False
3   x           active      2019-01-04  2019-01-04  False
4   a           canciled    2019-01-05  2019-01-05  False
```

Then you can remove the rows where you are not interested in the result.

This could be speeded up by using the `df.groupby()` but it complicates the indexing.